# RealityKit – Animate a transform on a loop

Tags: swift, animation, augmented-reality, realitykit

I can't figure out how to have the move function below repeat in order to create a constant rotation on a simple meshResource. Any suggestions?

```
var transform = sphereEntity.transform
transform.rotation =  simd_quatf(angle: .pi, axis: [0,1,0])
let anim = sphereEntity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: sphereEntity.parent, duration: 5.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.move()` instance method starts working when it's placed after the line entity added to a scene.

```
let boxEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 1.0), 
                       materials: [SimpleMaterial()])

var transform = boxEntity.transform

transform.rotation =  simd_quatf(angle: .pi, axis: [0, 1, 0])
    
let boxAnchor = AnchorEntity()
boxAnchor.children.append(boxEntity)
arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
    
boxEntity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: nil, duration: 5.0)
```

> At the moment (**December 23, 2022**) all RealityKit's `.move()` methods still can't loop.

Answer (score 1):

Looping an animation *is* possible by subscribing to the `AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted` event.

You'll have to move your animation logic into a separate function which you call  once. Inside this function you subscribe to the `PlaybackCompleted` event. When this event is fired you call the same animation function.

You can subscribe to `AnimationEvents` by using the `Scene.subscribe()` method:

```swift
func subscribe<E>(to event: E.Type, 
                  on sourceObject: EventSource? = nil, 
                  _ handler: @escaping (E) -> Void) -> Cancellable where E : Event
```

Please note that you'll have to import the Combine framework to be able to use this:

```swift
import Combine
```

The animation function then looks like this:

```swift
// This needs to be an instance variable, otherwise it'll
// get deallocated immediately and the animation won't start.
var animUpdateSubscription: Cancellable?

func animate(entity: HasTransform,
             angle: Float,
             axis: SIMD3<Float>,
             duration: TimeInterval,
             loop: Bool)
{
    var transform = entity.transform
    // We'll add the rotation to the current rotation
    transform.rotation *= simd_quatf(angle: angle, axis: axis)
    entity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: entity.parent, duration: duration)
    
    // Checks if we should loop and if we have already subscribed
    // to the AnimationEvent. We only need to do this once. 
    guard loop,
          animUpdateSubscription == nil
    else { return }
    
    animUpdateSubscription = scene.subscribe(to: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self, 
                                             on: entity, 
    { _ in
        self.animate(entity: entity, 
                     angle: angle, 
                     axis: axis, 
                     duration: duration, 
                     loop: loop)
    })
}
```

Now you can call this function once to trigger a looped animation:

```swift
animate(entity: entity, 
        angle: angle, 
        axis: axis, 
        duration: duration, 
        loop: loop)
```

Comment: I tried this, and the animation plays once, but event handler never fires, so it never loops. I'm not sure if something changed in the last two years or if I'm missing something -- very new to Swift and iOS dev in general, so that could easily be the case!