# Continuous-looping animations in RealityKit

Tags: ios, swift, combine, realitykit

I am writing an app that uses RealityKit. I want one of the entities in my AR scene to animate (rotate on its X axis) continuously.

I can get it to spin 180º once on load, and I can add a slider to my UI that controls its rotation, but I can't get it to animate continuously.

If any of this matters: I am using the latest stable versions of everything as of June 2023, no betas. Ventura 13.4, Xcode 14.3.1, Swift 5.8.1. Targeting iOS 16.4.

Here is a standalone demo of the issue, which I am trying out via Xcode Preview.

```swift
import Combine
import RealityFoundation
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI

struct ARKitPOC: View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State private var animUpdateSubscription: Cancellable?

    func makeUIView (context: Context) -> ARView {
        let redMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, roughness: 0.05, isMetallic: false)

        let boxResource = MeshResource.generateBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, depth: 1.0, cornerRadius: 0.1, splitFaces: false)
        let boxEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: boxResource, materials: [redMaterial])
        boxEntity.name = "box"
        boxEntity.position.z = -2
        
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(world: .zero)
        anchorEntity.name = "anchor"
        anchorEntity.addChild(boxEntity)

        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        arView.cameraMode = .nonAR
        
        rotateForever(scene: arView.scene,
                      entity: boxEntity,
                      angle: -.pi,
                      axis: [0,0,1],
                      duration: 1.0)

        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ arView: ARView, context: Context) {
    }

    func rotateForever(scene: RealityFoundation.Scene,
                       entity: HasTransform,
                       angle: Float,
                       axis: SIMD3<Float>,
                       duration: TimeInterval) {
        if animUpdateSubscription == nil {
            animUpdateSubscription = scene.subscribe(to: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self,
                                                     on: entity,
                                                     { _ in
                print("subscription triggered")
                self.rotateForever(scene: scene,
                                   entity: entity,
                                   angle: angle,
                                   axis: axis,
                                   duration: duration)
            })
            print("subscription:", animUpdateSubscription)
        }

        var transform = entity.transform
        transform.rotation *= simd_quatf(angle: angle, axis: axis)
        entity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: entity.parent, duration: duration, timingFunction: .linear)
    }
}

struct ARKitPOC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ARKitPOC()
    }
}
```

Here, I render a red cube into the scene and trigger a looping animation that rotates it 180º from its current orientation. Completion of that animation is supposed to result in an event, which should trigger another animation, such that the cube rotates indefinitely.

I've been searching, and have found this technique recommended in several places:
[RealityKit – Animate a transform on a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514348/realitykit-animate-a-transform-on-a-loop),
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66916901/535401,
https://rozengain.medium.com/quick-realitykit-tutorial-2-looping-animations-gestures-ee518b06b7f6

However, the call to `scene.subscribe(to:on:_:)` is returning nil, and the event handler I provided never gets invoked, so the animation only ever happens once.

The use of `scene.subsribe` required that I import Combine, which leads me to believe that this chunk of code:

```
            animUpdateSubscription = scene.subscribe(to: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self,
                                                     on: entity,
                                                     { _ in
```

is shorthand for this Combine-style subscription:

```
            animUpdateSubscription = scene.publisher(for: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self, on: entity)
                                          .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
```

I get exactly the same behavior with that substitution.

<s>Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/scene/subscribe(to:on:_:)) says nothing about the possibility of a nil return value. Ditto for the [proposed Combine equivalent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/sink(receivevalue:)). What am I missing here?</s> (see update below)

### Update

By changing to the `publisher(...).sink(...)` approach, then chaining a call to `print("publisher(for:)")` between those, I can see the following in my log output:

```
publisher(for:): receive subscription: (RealityFoundation.REEventDispatcher<__C.REAnimationHasCompletedEvent>.(unknown context at $10b680970).EventSubscription<RealityKit.Scene.CorePublisher<__C.REAnimationHasCompletedEvent>.(unknown context at $10b686788).Inner<Combine.Publishers.CompactMap<RealityKit.Scene.CorePublisher<__C.REAnimationHasCompletedEvent>, RealityKit.AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted>.(unknown context at $10a11e878).Inner<Combine.Publishers.Print<RealityKit.Scene.Publisher<RealityKit.AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted>>.(unknown context at $10a119ff8).Inner<Combine.Subscribers.Sink<RealityKit.AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted, Swift.Never>>>>>)
publisher(for:): request unlimited
publisher(for:): receive cancel
```

So, a valid subscription is getting created, but then it's getting canceled almost immediately. How do I figure out what's doing that? Is the `Swift.Never` or the `unknown context` near the end of the first line meaningful?

Comment: I have _part_ of an answer: `makeUIView` and `updateUIView` in a UIViewRepresentable are not allowed to update SwiftUI state variables. I'm told I need to use a coordinator, and `rotateForever` should be a function of the coordinator. I'm still working out exactly what that looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, with some outside help.

In SwiftUI, you can't store into @State during makeUIView or updateUIView. The reason being that mutations to State are one of the signals that triggers a SwiftUI View to update, which means mutating a State causes SwiftUI to call updateUIView to give you a change to react to the new state. Setting State from inside updateUIView then creates a cycle, which SwiftUI tries to break.

It was recommended that I move the `rotateForever` function into a Coordinator, as follows:

```swift
import Combine
import RealityFoundation
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI

struct POC: View {
    var body: some View {
        POCViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

final class Coordinator {
    var subscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    func rotateForever(arView: ARView,
                       scene: RealityFoundation.Scene,
                       entity: HasTransform,
                       angle: Float,
                       axis: SIMD3<Float>,
                       duration: TimeInterval) {
        var transform = entity.transform
        transform.rotation *= simd_quatf(angle: angle, axis: axis)
        entity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: entity.parent, duration: duration, timingFunction: .linear)

        if subscription == nil {
            subscription = scene.publisher(for: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self, on: entity)
                                          .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                self.rotateForever(arView: arView,
                                   scene: scene,
                                   entity: entity,
                                   angle: angle,
                                   axis: axis,
                                   duration: duration)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct POCViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State private var animUpdateSubscription: Cancellable?

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
      Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let redMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, roughness: 0.05, isMetallic: false)

        let boxResource = MeshResource.generateBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, depth: 1.0, cornerRadius: 0.1, splitFaces: false)
        let boxEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: boxResource, materials: [redMaterial])
        boxEntity.name = "box"
        boxEntity.position.z = -2
        
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(world: .zero)
        anchorEntity.name = "anchor"
        anchorEntity.addChild(boxEntity)
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        arView.cameraMode = .nonAR

        context.coordinator.rotateForever(arView: arView,
                                          scene: arView.scene,
                                          entity: boxEntity,
                                          angle: -.pi,
                                          axis: [0,0,1],
                                          duration: 1.0)

        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
}

struct POC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        POC()
    }
}
```

With this code, the box rotates smoothly forever. I've removed the debugging `print` statements that were present in the question, but if you add them back, you can see it working as intended.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution.  I used your code exactly as you suggested and my Entities rotate exactly pi radians and then stop.  What am I missing to make it forever?  I notice that your ```POCViewContainer``` declares the variable ```animUpdateSubscription``` and then doesn't use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the animation won't occur because your anchor has no anchor component set. try setting its target to a world transform or position.
If an entity's anchor changes in some way  the animation does end up stopping - or not running if the animation is called before an entity is anchored in the scene.

There is also a spin animation in the swift package RealityUI to make it easier:

https://github.com/maxxfrazer/RealityUI/wiki/Animations

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I’m pretty new to all of this; could you be more specific, ideally with some code? I don’t know what it means to set an anchor component on my anchor, nor how to set its target to a world transform.

Comment: Yeah for sure, just set your anchor entity to something like this: `AnchorEntity(world: .zero)`, so it will be anchored at the world origin (where the camera is on initialisation)
You can check if an entity is anchored in the scene at any time with isAnchored:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/isanchored

Comment: Okay, I changed `let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity()` to `let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(world: .zero)`. No change in apparent behavior.

Comment: Also, to be clear: the animation _does_ occur -- it just doesn't loop. I believe the problem lies somewhere in the subscription to the AnimationCompleted event.

Comment: ah i see! sorry i thought it wasn’t animating at all, my mistake.

Comment: check out the rotation animation in RealityUI, as that does work. either use that one directly or compare with your implementation and you’ll get to the solution.